# Bind CapsLock+hjkl to arrow keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb, xmodmap

I want to bind <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> / <kbd>J</kbd> / <kbd>K</kbd> / <kbd>L</kbd> to arrow keys. 
I found two ways that each have some issues:

**Solution 1**

Using `xkb`:  Edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` first block.

```
            # replace Caps with AltGr
            key <CAPS> { [ ISO_Level3_Shift            ] };
            # Add vim cursor keys to be accessed with AltGr
            key <AB02> { [ x, X, Delete, Delete        ] };
            key <AC02> { [ s, S, KP_Enter, KP_Enter    ] };
            key <AC03> { [ d, D, Next, Next            ] };
            key <AC04> { [ f, F, BackSpace, BackSpace  ] };
            key <AC06> { [ h, H , Left, Left           ] };
            key <AC07> { [ j, J, Down, Down            ] };
            key <AC08> { [ k, K, Up, Up                ] };
            key <AC09> { [ l, L, Right, Right          ] };
            key <AD07> { [ u, U, Prior, Prior          ] };
            key <AE03> { [ 3, section, Home, Home      ] };
            key <AE04> { [ 4, dollar, End, End         ] };
```

but this answer doesn't work in Java programs (e.g., IntelliJ),
so I should use solution 2.

**Solution 2**

Using `xmodmap`: Create `~/.xmodmap` file with following content:

```
keycode 66 = Mode_switch
keysym h = h H Left
keysym l = l L Right
keysym k = k K Up
keysym j = j J Down
keysym u = u U Prior
keysym i = i I Home
keysym o = o O End
keysym p = p P Next
```

and then run `xmodmap ~/.xmodmap` command.

**Problem:** This solution breaks other layouts. It works in English, but when I switch other layout, e.g., to Russian, I cannot type letters on these keys and <kbd>Caps</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> / <kbd>J</kbd> / <kbd>K</kbd> / <kbd>L</kbd> also don't work
until I switch back to English. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Other options might be to look into keynav, or get a programmable keyboard like en ergodox-ez.

Comment: @Henrik But I want to bind this keys on my own laptop's keyboard

Comment: That rules out getting a programmable keyboard, but not keynav.

Comment: @Henrik As far as I understand , keynav is for mouse navigation, but I want keyboard navigation to navigate between characters, Furthermore keynav need to start shortcut and then we can navigate, but i want to navigate without a start shortcut.(just same as keyboard arrow keys).

Comment: I have an example in my dotfiles of how this is done: https://github.com/Ace-Cassidy/dotfiles

Answer (score 1):

On linux, I strongly recommend [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd/).
This [example config](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd/blob/master/examples/nav-layer.conf)  will achieve even more than you want (but you can prune it manually if desired)

```
# Goal:
#
# To create a vi like navigation layer accessible by pressing H J K L while having capslock pressed
# otherwise behave like the control key (when held) and escape when tapped.
#
# In essence we want:
#
#  - capslock+h = left
#  - capslock+j = down
#  - capslock+k = up
#  - capslock+l = right
#
#  - capslock+shift+h = C-left
#  - capslock+shift+l = C-right
#  - capslock+shift+j = C-down
#  - capslock+shift+k = C-up
#
#  - capslock = escape (when tapped)
#
# In all other instances capslock should behave as normal control:
#
#  - capslock+a = C-a
#  - capslock+b = C-b
#  - capslock+c = C-c
#  ...
#  - capslock+shift+i = C-S-i
#  - capslock+shift+k = C-S-k
#  ....
```

[kmonad](https://github.com/kmonad/kmonad) would be an alternative

Answer (score 0):

See the example here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension#Caps_hjkl_as_vimlike_arrow_keys

It should work in all apps perfectly.

I will try to elaborate this answer and submit more complete example later.